# Combinatorics - Number of arrangements in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutations

> Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_8$ be some distinct people. 
> In how many different ways can we arrange all of them in a circle such that $x_1$ sits in front of $x_2$ and, $x_3$ doesn't sit near $x_4$?

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong: We can choose out of $x_3, x_4, \dots, x_8$ a subset of 3, let's say $x_3, x_4, x_5$ as those who are placed between $x_1$ and $x_2$ at the right side.
Since each subset defines an arrangement for the left side, we divide by two. Then for each subset, we compute each internal arrangement for the elements in the left side and so for the right side, hence, we end up with: ${6 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \cdot 3!$

Secondly, I compute the number of such arrangements where $x_3$ sits near $x_4$: I have two options where I want this pair to sit: near $x_1$ or near $x_2$. Suppose I chose $x_1$ then I have 2 options to choose which one out of $x_3, x_4$ I want to place near $x_1$. Finally, there are 4 options to place an element near $x_3, x_4$ and taking internal arrangements for the other 3 elements left get me to $2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot3!$. Now we subtract it from the total number of arrangements.

However it seems like the answer is incorrect and I'm curious to know what I've missed. I tried to use analog as the number of circles in a simple graph $G$ which satisfies the given constraints, to which I presumed, would give me intuition but just made it more vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you choose three people among $x_3,\ldots,x_8$. Moreover, you will, or not, have a constraint in function of if $x_3$/$x_4$ belong to this set or not, and what are $A$ and $B$ ?

For this kind of problem, begin by getting rid of the contraints. Choose a position for $x_1$ ($8$ possibilities), then place $x_2$ in front of it ($1$ possibility). Then place $x_3$, it leads to two possible cases,

$1)$ $x_3$ is next to $x_1$ or $x_2$ ($4$ possibilities)

$2)$ $x_3$ is not next to $x_1$ neither $x_2$ ($2$ possibilities).

In the first case, it leaves you $4$ choices for the position of $x_4$ because the only left place next to $x_3$ is forbidden. In the second one, you only have $3$ choices for $x_4$ because there are $2$ forbidden places next to $x_3$. Finally, place $x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8$ (no constraint thus $4! = 24$ possibilities)

Finally, the total number of possible placements are,
$$
N = \underbrace{8}_{x_1} \cdot \underbrace{1}_{x_2} \cdot (\underbrace{4}_{x_3, \textrm{ case } 1)} \cdot \underbrace{4}_{x_4, \textrm{ case 1)}} + \underbrace{2}_{x_3, \textrm{ case } 2)} \cdot \underbrace{3}_{x_4, \textrm{ case 2)}}) \cdot \underbrace{24}_{x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8} = 4224.
$$
If you only count the number of circles "up to rotation", divide the result by $8$ to get $N = 528$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant to $x_1, x_2$ instead $A, B$. 
So initially ignoring the fact we count up to a circle & by dividing to different cases we reduce the constraints which make this problem relatively simple. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Your answer seems a bit confused, so let me give a simple method.

As is the convention, unless it is explicitly mentioned, the seats are taken to be unnumbered, and rotations don't create a new arrangement.

- Place $x_1,x_2$ on a diameter, $3$ seats are available in each half.
- To keep $x_3,x_4$ apart, there are $\binom62-4= 11$ patterns, $22$ arrangements.
- Permute the the remaining $4$ in $4!$ ways
- Putting it together, $22*4! = 528$ arrangements